# Почему подкладывают свинью?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

**Подложить свинью** — значит сделать гадость, напакостить кому-то.
Но почему именно свинью? И откуда вообще взялась эта поговорка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

для начала - первоисточник скописаченного Марк Из текста:

- Да как ты можешь мне все это говорить? Никогда ему не прощу! Он такую свинью мне подложил!

Свинью подложил... Красочное выражение, не правда ли? Сделал, устроил большую неприятность - вот что это значит. И сразу представляешь себе большую, даже огромную свинью, которую тебе кто-то подкладывает... куда? Например, на стол. Представляешь, а потом задумываешься: почему именно свинью выбрали для того, чтобы доставить тебе огорчение? И та ли свинья имеется в виду?

По традиционному толкованию свинья в этом выражении означает вовсе не животное, а "строй клином, кабаном, кабаньей головой для пролома вражеских рядов, для нападения". Как вы помните из уроков истории, в 1242 году немецкие рыцари вклинились "свиньей" в расположение русских войск на Чудском озере, но попали в "русские клещи", особое контррасположение войск Александра Невского.

Но, как часто это бывает с фразеологизмами, не все ясно с происхождением подложенной свиньи. "Историческая" версия, уверяет языковед В. Мокиенко, не единственная. По другой - выражение "свинью подложить" могло восходить к религиозному запрету у мусульман (или, добавим мы, у иудеев) есть свинину. Представим себе, что некто мог коварно подкладывать верующим свинину, чтобы подстроить неприятность или зло подшутить...

И, наконец, еще две версии, более безобидные. По мнению того же Мокиенко, это выражение можно толковать и на основе правил народной игры "в свинки", где игроку подкладывали неподходящую для удара бабку - "свинку". А еще это могло быть народной шуткой типа "убил бобра!" (то есть совершил грубую оплошность). Такая фразочка имеет широкие параллели в славянских языках: в украинском - "лиса зловити", что значит "опалить полу одежды"; в чешском - "kozla odrit"(ободрать козла), что значит "ошибиться". Во французском же языке в неприятное положение ставят, говоря "jeter un chat aux jambes de quelgu un" (бросить кота под ноги кому-то).

У нас - никаких лис, козлов и котов! У нас в таких случаях подкладывают свинью.
(С)Марина Королева.

[Происхождение фразеологизма "свинью подложить" | Российская газета](http://www.rg.ru/2007/11/15/koroleva.html)

Есть еще версии, опустим. По большому счету, критики все не выдерживают, за исключением, разве что игры в бабки. По крайней мере она объясняет, почему свинью (не свинину, заметьте!) именно подкладывают, а во-вторых, базируется на русской народной традиции, а не древней истории или метналитете совсем не русского народа.

Answer (score 2):

По традиционному толкованию свинья в этом выражении означает вовсе не животное, а "строй клином, кабаном, кабаньей головой для пролома вражеских рядов, для нападения". Как вы помните из уроков истории, в 1242 году немецкие рыцари вклинились "свиньей" в расположение русских войск на Чудском озере, но попали в "русские клещи", особое контррасположение войск Александра Невского. Треугольный боевой порядок «свинья» считался весьма грозным. Возможно, потому-то слова "подложить свинью" (кому-либо) и стали означать: устроить крупную неприятность. Любопытно, что в немецком языке идиоматическое выражение "иметь свинью" означает "везение". «Er hat Schwein» (он имеет свинью) – ему везет.

Но, как часто это бывает с фразеологизмами, не все ясно с происхождением подложенной свиньи. "Историческая" версия, уверяет языковед В. Мокиенко, не единственная. По другой - выражение "свинью подложить" могло восходить к религиозному запрету у мусульман (или, добавим мы, у иудеев) есть свинину. Представим себе, что некто мог коварно подкладывать верующим свинину, чтобы подстроить неприятность или зло подшутить...

И, наконец, еще две версии, более безобидные. По мнению того же Мокиенко, это выражение можно толковать и на основе правил народной игры "в свинки", где игроку подкладывали неподходящую для удара бабку - "свинку". А еще это могло быть народной шуткой типа "убил бобра!" (то есть совершил грубую оплошность). Такая фразочка имеет широкие параллели в славянских языках: в украинском - "лиса зловити", что значит "опалить полу одежды"; в чешском - "kozla odrit"(ободрать козла), что значит "ошибиться". Во французском же языке в неприятное положение ставят, говоря "jeter un chat aux jambes de quelgu un" (бросить кота под ноги кому-то).

Comment: Скажите, Марк Из, почему все эти версии в виде устойчивых выражений не упоминаются Далем? 1886 - впервые у Степняка-Кравчинского... Какой Александр Невский, какие мусульмане и евреи??
Ну вот, полюбуйтесь :
> М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. За рубежом (1880-1881) Всякий день мы видим во сне каждый свою свинью, и это уж не смущает нас. /////
Эти условия были положительно тяжелы для моего бюджета, но страх вновь увидеть во сне свинью был так велик, что я, не долго думая, согласился./////
Весь вечер я просидел один и потому ночью опять видел во сне свинью.

Свинья - символ неприятностей, настоящая свинья!

Comment: Сказать кому-нибудь **свинью** - обычное выражение неудовольствия, отсюда и пошло, без всяких хитрых этимологий.

Comment: Получается,  что  выражение  восходит  к  соннику,  к  приметам.

Answer (score 0):

А может и так, спать пьяного в хлев к свиньям в обнимку. Проснулся и на, тебе, подложили.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то султану Османской империи Мураду в охраняемые  покои подложили голову свинью, чем хотели его унизить и оскорбить. Сделать такое мог только приближённый. Вполне возможно, что выражение "подложить свинью" идет оттуда.

Answer (score 0):

ПОДЛОЖИТЬ СВИНЬЮ.Во время осады первого храма
финикийцами,евреям для жертвоприношения требовались козлы.Они опускали со стен две корзины. золота а взамен им ложили в корзины два мешка с козликами.Однажды им подложили вместо козликов свиней.17 талмуза.Вот и возникло это выражение

Comment: Не понял, так — «им ложили», или «им подложили»?

Answer (score 0):

В древности при осаде какого-то города вырыли подкоп и сложили туда свиней с бревнами. Температура горения со свиным жиром была настолько высока, что за́мок выгорел дотла!